# Using 2 Aggregation in Having Clause

Tags: sqlite, having-clause

If I have table that contains data for all the teams from many leagues, how I can get the first team from each league? The first team in each league should be the team with most point, or if points are equal the team with best goal difference (GF-GA)

For example:

| League | Team | GF | GA | Points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Champion Group A | Bayren | 18 | 5 | 16 |
| Champion Group A | Atlteico Madrid | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| Champion Group H | PSG | 13 | 6 | 12 |
| Champion Group H | RB Leipzig | 11 | 12 | 12 |

I want to get result like:

| League | Team |
| --- | --- |
| Champion Group A | Bayren |
| Champion Group H | PSG |

```
SELECT TEAM, LEAGUE
FROM LEAGUES_TABLE
GROUP BY LEAGUE
HAVING MAX(POINTS)  //or if point equal use MAX(GF-GA)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
SELECT league, team, gf, ga, points
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY league ORDER BY points DESC, gf - ga DESC) rn
  FROM leagues_table
)
WHERE rn = 1
```

Or with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT lt1.* FROM leagues_table lt1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM leagues_table lt2
  WHERE lt2.league = lt1.league 
    AND (lt2.points > lt1.points 
         OR (lt2.points = lt1.points AND lt2.gf - lt2.ga > lt1.gf - lt1.ga)
        ) 
)
```

Or with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT lt1.* FROM leagues_table lt1
WHERE lt1.rowid = (
  SELECT lt2.rowid
  FROM leagues_table lt2
  WHERE lt2.league = lt1.league
  ORDER BY lt2.points DESC, lt2.gf - lt2.ga DESC
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=12449d9862dac1f3e1f0efb9ff4b2484).
Results:

| League | Team | GF | GA | Points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Champion Group A | Bayren | 18 | 5 | 16 |
| Champion Group H | PSG | 13 | 6 | 12 |

Comment: Thanks. I'm not familiar with the PARTITION syntax. I used the NOT EXISTS solution and it works great

Answer (score -1):

Try this. I didn't test this, but in my mind, this should work.

```
with team_points_ranked as (SELECT TEAM, LEAGUE, GA, GF
FROM LEAGUES_TABLE
GROUP BY LEAGUE
HAVING MAX(POINTS))

select TEAM, LEAGUE
from team_points_ranked
group by LEAGUE
having MAX(GF-GA)
```

Comment: It doesn't seems to be working. If I understand the syntax then it first creates view with the team with most point and then try to get the team with Max(GF-GA). Since the view already getting the MAX(points), then it won't return team with the same points under the same league. bdw, I didn't mark it as not useful, but I think someone mark it as it missing explanations. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This is what happens when I don't test the code I suggest. lol. No problem. I was thinking if there are 2 teams with equal max points, then it would return both teams in "team_points_ranked". Are you getting a syntax error? And yes, I should have added explanation. Newbie here and learning it the hard way.

Comment: It doesn't have syntax error, but will always get the same team with max point, regardless of the (GF-GA).